# IMPDP in Oracle 11g - From One Schema to other Schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-dump

I used to run commands to get Oracle database backup in the old way using 'exp' and 'imp fromuser touser. Now, I am trying to user new command to take backup 'expdp' and 'impdp'.

### Steps:

1. Got backup using expdp with schema parameter on the production server. my username is 'xxx' (Not sure it's fully exported with procedures, function, and view).
2. Now, on my dev server first I made another user called 'yyy'. I gave directory access to user 'yyy' and trying to run command impdp as below.

   C:\impdp yyy/yyy remap_schema=xxx:yyy directory=abc dumpfile=123.dmp logfile=123.log

Now, I am getting an error like the below.

```
Import: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Thursday, 24 January, 2013 9:53:58

Copyright (c) 2003, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining, and Real Application Testing options
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "yyy.SYS_IMPORT_FULL_05"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 978
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Do I miss any steps? like I have to create a job or anything, not sure. basically, I got backup from one user and need to restore on another user in Oracle.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User yyy will need appropriate privledges necessary to create the objects.

See:  privileges required to import objects into your own schema.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#BABFHCBI

Also:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#CJAIBFJG

Many Data Pump Export and Import operations require the user to have the DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role and/or the DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE role. These roles are automatically defined for Oracle databases when you run the standard scripts that are part of database creation. (Note that although the names of these roles contain the word FULL, these roles are actually required for all export and import modes, not only Full mode.)

The DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role affects only export operations. The DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE role affects import operations and operations that use the Import SQLFILE parameter. These roles allow users performing exports and imports to do the following:

•Perform the operation outside the scope of their schema

Comment: Thanks for the oracle links.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, import user donot have permission on import database directory.
In the Import db,
select directory_name,directory_path from dba_directories;
It will show the directory names
sql>grant read,write on directory abc to ;

Robertson
Oracle Database SME
+91-9886321339